# +/-0.5LSB or just round?

Tags: adc

I just looked back at an old model for calculation ADC reading error.

When looking at it realised I have +/-0.5LSB for the worst case (WC) positive and negative channel. I can't really figure out why I added this when I also have a round function around it.

Wouldn't it just be enough to have a rounding? to the closest integer value?
I'm asking because I know I put a lot of time in making that model and I've hard time to believe I didn't had a thought about it.

The idea of the model is to round every value to an whole integer, to emulate what an ADC would approximately see in real life but in Spice.

Comment: If yo are modeling a perfect ADC, just round. If you are modeling a real ADC, add an error source corresponding to the INL and DNL errors in its datasheet.

Comment: I've an error for the summed square root mean of the ADC, already.

Comment: An ADC would truncate i.e. round down always.

Comment: That is a good point @Andy aka , That would explain why I had -0.5LSB because the rounding I'm using rounds "normal".

Comment: Unless there are only a very few bits, other noise sources are usually a lot higher than the quantization noise, so it's kind of a moot point (eg. on a 24-bit ADC). WC means something else to me.